# ORACLE SQL: view, which will only show details of employees if it is used between the hours of 11:00 and 13:00

Tags: oracle10g

I have a data table called EMPLOYEES with basic data like employee number, name, job, and salary. 
I know how to make a view but is there a way of making a view whose data can only be seen or accessed within certain hours, say between 11:00 and 13:00?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add condition to WHERE clause of your view:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE to_char(SYSDATE, 'HH24') BETWEEN 11 AND 13
```

Comment: I would have more confidence in to_char(SYSDATE, 'HH24') BETWEEN '11' AND '13'